# Problem with .Net tracelistener

Tags: .net

I am using .Net tracelistener for enabling logging in the application. My application is multi threaded .Net service. Under heavy load .Net tracing throws following error.
Has anyone any idea why this is happning and any resolution for this?

```
System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs
System.IO.IOException
mscorlib
The process cannot access the file 'C:\035_Prg.log' because it is being used by another process.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.WriteHeader(String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String format, Object[] args)

   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String format, Object[] args)
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceInformation(String message)
```

Comment: Did you try to stop your service or IIS where you hosting your service, or kill asp_net process in task manger?

Comment: Are you sure you're not adding the same TraceListener twice? This can cause this kind of problem. Otherwise, what is exactly the TraceListener class you're using?

Comment: I am using Tracesource class for tracelisteners.

Comment: Have u tried checking the IsThreadSafeProperty on the tracelister. according to msdn tracelistern might not be thread safe under some conditions. You can also have a look a this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485130/windbg-tracelistener-and-saturated-threadpool this might lead u in th right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There are various [aspects of thread-safety](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2009/01/08/Disable-Trace-UseGlobalLock-For-Better-Tracing-Performance.aspx) in TraceListeners that should help prevent this. They allow locking either globally on the collection of listeners you are writing, on the level of an individual listener, or no locking by the framework at all in the case where your TraceListener [announces itself as thread safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.isthreadsafe.aspx). What the framework does not do is lock the file itself, so be sure to check the obvious such as some other process on your machine or other code in your application that could be locking the file.

You may also want to consider whether changing the granularity of your tracing may help. I typically define separate static TraceSources for each module and/or activity of my application. Doing this, and turning off UseGlobalLock as Rory suggests in [his article](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2009/01/08/Disable-Trace-UseGlobalLock-For-Better-Tracing-Performance.aspx) may reduce contention.